# Не создается папка “allure-results” в проекте Allure+JUnit+Maven

Tags: java, maven, allure

На данный момент изучаю Allure по статьям https://habr.com/company/sberbank/blog/358836/
https://habr.com/company/sberbank/blog/359302/
Решил попробовать повторить на простейшем тестовом проекте, но папка allure-results не создалась в target:

pom.xml:

```
<groupId>me</groupId>
<artifactId>alluretest</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.20.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
    <allure-junit4.version>2.6.0</allure-junit4.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>${allure-junit4.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"</argLine>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>io.qameta.allure.junit4.AllureJunit4</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                        <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

alluretest.java:

```
import io.qameta.allure.Step;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class alluretest {
    @Step
    public static void checkSumStep(int num1, int num2, int expectedSum) {
        Assert.assertTrue("Сумма слагаемых не соответствует ожидаемому значению", num1 + num2 == expectedSum);
    }
    @Test
    public void simpleTest2() {
        checkSumStep(3, 2, 5);
        checkSumStep(5, 4, 9);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо проблема была в том, что я билдил и запускал проект из среды (Intellij IDEA). Зайдя в консоли в папку с проектом выполнил команды `mvn clean test` и `mvn site` - папка allure-results появилась, внутри даже появился json, правда allure-results оказалась не в target, а в папке с проектом. Но после выполнения `cd allure-results` и `allure serve` html - отчет оказался пустым. Но это уже другой вопрос